# Both POST/GET requests yield a 404 error in Postman. Is my Express routing to blame?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, mean-stack

I am intending to set up a Node.js server with MongoDB to handle HTTP CRUD requests. Upon setting up my endpoint I was initially able to receive POST/GET requests, however the handling of the document objects became the issue. Upon trying to fix this issue I am now unable to POST/GET at all? Is this simply a syntax issue or is my code doomed?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var QRCode = require('qrcode');
var canvasu = require('canvas');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var db;
var collection
var Patient = require('./ShiftAssist/models/patientModel');
var router = express.Router();
```

''
CODE FOR CONNECTION
''

```
router.get('/patients/:Pnum', function(req,res,next){    
    Patient.findOne({Pnum:req.params.Pnum},function(err,patient){
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(patient);
    })
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
});
```

Expected: GET request to http://127.0.0.1:3000/patients/XXXXXX with a document identifier, returns entire document

Actual: Timeout Error

Comment: `GET  http://127.0.0.1:3000/patients/XXXXXX` will match to your router `/patients/:Pnum`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I attempted both GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/patients/XXXXXX and http://127.0.0.1:3000/patients/?Pnum=XXXXXX and both yielded a 404

Comment: @CalvinWoo Welcome to Stackoverflow. The post indicates the request is sent to `/patients` with `?Pnum=...` as the query string.

Comment: @CalvinWoo Your updated comment suggests the correct route was also attempted. Another thing that stands out is that the path is defined on `router` and not on `app`.

Comment: @CalvinWoo Are you sure your `router ` variable has been used? Like this `app.use('/', router);`

Comment: @Boaz that appears to be one of the reasons why it is 404ing. However now it appears to time out now. I inserted app.use('/', router); into the top code block.

Comment: @CalvinWoo timed out error, do you have any handler for  the `next(err)` function, I think just call `res.send(err); ` instead of `next(err)`, the  error will be send to your client.

Answer (score 0):

try to change you route by `/patients/:Pnum`
and your request should be  http://127.0.0.1:3000/patients/XXXXXX

source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

EDIT: Code i used so far

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/patients/:Pnum', function (req, res, next) {
    setTimeout(() => res.json({ ok: req.params.Pnum }), 1000)
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: The route is already correct. The oversight is indeed in the request itself. The parameter is included in the path as `/:Pnum`. Adding it to the request query string as `?Pnum=...` defeats the point, as it sends the request to `/patients` which is a very different route.

Comment: Attempted to change the route, however 404 issue persists.

Comment: @Boaz I'm not quite sure what you mean. How should I format the query?

Comment: i have seen you are using router did you wrote an `app.use` for use it ?

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon that appears to be one of the issues, code has been updated. However the request appears to time out now.

Comment: move down the `app.use` statement to be just before the app.listen.

Comment: Moved app.use statement, however request still times out.

Comment: @CalvinWoo It would be best to update the question with the new code and error.

Comment: tried your code without db request and it's working, the issue is maybe in the use of Mongoose, did you try to log the patient response ?

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I just tried to log the Patient response by passing the whole Patient.findOne() function into console.log(), however it still appears to time out.

Comment: do you have an output if you log the patient ? The issue is coming from your db request which i think do not return anything